# Parse.com Unable to store special characters

Tags: parse-platform

I'm building an iOS App with the backend using Parse. I received a Parse Error 122 whenever I try to store ' " & @ characters. Is there a way to overcome this? The text field needs to allow users the freedom to type anything they want if not it may not be user friendly. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code you're using.  I assure you Parse can handle these characters, and unicode too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I read from the Parse blogs and Parser's reply, Parse expects data in UTF-8. So if you want to save data with special character, then you should first  encode your data as UTF-8. Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: You may be right. Could you shed some light on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Based on your programming language(objective-c I hope) search on google and I am sure there are lots of examples.